# Allow scrolling image up and down in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView`, I also implemented this method:

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}
```

For the image to resize inside the `UIScrollView`, but I want to allow the user to change the y axis of the image and move it up and down, not just to pinch and resize.

I set the `UIImageView` `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` and gave the `UIScrollView` a `maximumZoomScale` of 0.5f

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a bigger `contentSize` in the `UIScrollView` than the `Frame`. Then set the `Frame` of the `UIImageView` the same size as the `UIScrollView contentSize`.

**Example**

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
  [self.imageView setFrame:CGSizeMake(320, self.view.frame.size.height* 1.5)];
  [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, self.view.frame.size.height* 1.5)];
}
```

Comment: I did that, and it worked, but as I zoom again and resize the image back to it's original frame, it goes back to as it was before.

Comment: Have you tried maybe setting the minimumZoomScale to 1.5f?

Comment: no.. let me test what you gave me here and I'll update. Thanks man!

Comment: Well, it work's like a charm man, thank you very much! For some reason I thought it's going to be longer than that :)

Comment: I have another question, if the image starts after 1.5, how can I center it to the scrollview just at first launch, than after the user plays with it, let it move freely like it does right now